# Passing Data from one Functional Component to another

Tags: reactjs

I've only been coding in React.JS for a week now and have hit a roadblock while trying to pass data from one Functional component to another and then rendering that in the latter.
The idea is to pass the input to the `ListItems` component from the `InputBar` component.
In my opinion, an easier option would have been to simply return the `ListItem` component inside `InputBar` but I would like to try it in the below approach.

`InputBar` component

```
    import React,{ useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import ListItems from "../list_items/list_items";
    import "./input_bar.css";
    
    const InputBar = () => {
    
        const[userInput, setInput] = useState('');
    
        const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
            if(e.key === "Enter") {
                console.log({userInput})
                setInput('');
            }
        }
    
        const handleChange = (e) => {
            setInput(e.target.value);
        }
    
        //This is where I've passed the data from
        <ListItems enteredInput = {userInput}></ListItems>     
        
        return(
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Add Shopping Item" value={userInput} onChange={handleChange} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}></input>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default InputBar;
```

`ListItems` component

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./list_items.css";

const ListItems = (props) => {

    const newInput = {
        name : props.enteredInput
    };

    const data = [{name : "Kitkat 10"}, {name : "Kitkat 10"}, {name : "Kitkat 10"}, {name : "Kitkat 10"}, {name : "Kitkat 10"}];

    data.push(newInput);

    const[items, setItems] = useState(data);

    return(
        <div>
            {data.length === 0 ? <p>No Items Added</p> : items.map((key, value) => <div className="list_items">
                {items[value].name}
                {console.log(items)}
                <button className="x_button">X</button>
                <button className="purchase_button">Purchase</button>
            </div>)}
        </div>
    );
}

export default ListItems;
```

Upon initially loading the component, I see a ListItem created with nothing written on it and the console shows an undefined object already created without me putting anything in the `InputBar` Component. I have marked the new `ListItem` on the screenshot to show what I mean:
[image]

The console log:

```
0: {name: 'Kitkat 10'}
1: {name: 'Kitkat 10'}
2: {name: 'Kitkat 10'}
3: {name: 'Kitkat 10'}
4: {name: 'Kitkat 10'}
5: {name: undefined}    //The undefined object
length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Later On, If I try adding anything from the input, it neither updates the length of the array nor renders any new component in `ListItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redux, context api or any other state management library.
Update global state from input and use that global state in ListItems component.

Comment: This worked just fine. I used Context API

Comment: Maybe mobx can be used too, but I think it  may become complex

Answer (score 0):

You have to return something in a function component, your way is false and may cause problems. You must rely on your return, but in your case you just returned an input, and I am actually surprised that it has a component in it.

Let's have a look other details. In your ListItems, you get the props like:

```
const newInput = {
    name : props.enteredInput
};
```

And pushing it in your data:
`data.push(newInput);`

This means, what you get as a prop is pushed to your data.

And in your InputBar, you create ListItems like this:
`<ListItems enteredInput = {userInput}></ListItems>`
and your userInput is `''` since you create it like this:
`const[userInput, setInput] = useState('');`
What you give in your useState is the initial value.

What you can do is:
Create ListItems with the data as props, don't create data inside your ListItems. The data given to the ListItems must be created by useState. Your InputBar must update the data state and include the ListItems in its return.

```
const ListItems = (props) => {

    const data=props.data
  ....

}

const InputBars=()=> {

const [data,setData] = useState([])

return <>
       <input....>
        <ListItems data={data}>
<>

}
```

Comment: Can you please code the changes if that's alright?

Comment: Added a few deatils @coolhack7 , understand and implement in your own.